# DRF can't authorize account via token, always getting anonymous user object

Tags: jquery, python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am using TokenAuthentication and have model Profile for users:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participant = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And view for profile creating:

```
class ProfileView(LoggingMixin, GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return user's profile information
        """
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Create new profile
        """
        data = request.data.copy()
        data['user'] = request.user.id
        print data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data, context={"request":request})
        print serializer
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print 1
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I need to create profile object after registration. I am sending data from a web page via jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {"Authorization": "Token " + data.key},
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8002/v1/profiles/",
        data: JSON.stringify(profileDataToSend),
        success: function(){
            console.log('Success! 2');
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType : "application/json"
  });
```

Registration works fine, Token gets created, but when I try to send this request for creating a profile, linked to logged user, I get anonymous user object every time. 
In my settings I am setting :

```
DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES = "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication"
```

But still, can't understand why I can't get user logged in with my request. Where am I doing mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Idiot. Anonymous user was because I don't set

```
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

that's why.